# SQL Server find Unique rows on multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, unique

I have two columns in one table which when combined should be unique. I need a query to discover which rows do not have a unique combination. `Concat([Category], [SEL])` is what needs to be unique, neither are unique on their own.

I found the following `SELECT`, but I don't know how to adapt it for multiple columns.

```
SELECT [Category], [SEL] 
FROM [myTable] 
WHERE [Category] IN (SELECT [Category] 
                     FROM [myTable] 
                     GROUP BY [Category] 
                     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

Group by both columns.  The results will be combinations of `Category` and `SEL` that appear in more than one record.

```
SELECT [Category], [SEL] FROM [myTable] GROUP BY [Category], [SEL] HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```